Ubuntu 24.04 freezes after suspending
My computer is Dell G3 3590 with Ubuntu 24.04. When I suspend the system the system freezes.

This problem doesn't occur when I hibernate the system. I tried everything with grub.

Please edit the question and add all the things you have tried and any errors or messages you got. This is so no one tells you to do something you already have done.
